# ExcelDNA AppDomain could not be created

Tags: .net-4.8, excel-dna

When launching the .xll file for a minimal ExcelDNA add-in targeting .NET Framework 4.8, certain users see the following error:

> A problem occurred while the add-in was creating an isolated application domain and loading required assemblies.
>
> AppDomain could not be created

[image]

Many other users do not encounter this error. If we build the add-in for .NET 6, the affected users do not get the error. The add-in uses ExcelDna v1.7.0-rc6.

In the ExcelDNA source code, this error is raised by ExcelDnaLoader.cpp in two cases:

1. [Failure to get current AppDomain](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/blob/master/Source/ExcelDna/ExcelDnaLoader.cpp#L348) using [`ICorRuntimeHost::CurrentDomain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/icorruntimehost-currentdomain-method), and
2. [Failure to create new AppDomain](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/blob/master/Source/ExcelDna/ExcelDnaLoader.cpp#L445) using [`ICorRuntimeHost::CreateDomainEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/icorruntimehost-createdomainex-method)

(I note that `ICorRuntimeHost` appears in the docs under "Deprecated CLR hosting interfaces" )

What have we tried?

- the HRESULT 0x7DAEF100 doesn't appear to match any known value
- we haven't yet identified any characteristic of the affected users' machines which might explain why they hit this error but others don't. The Windows version and build doesn't seem to be the cause, for example
- we don't see any related events in Event Viewer

Given the deprecated technologies, I'm not hopeful about finding a solution (besides upgrading our add-in to .NET 6). But, here goes.

**How might we go about debugging this further?**

**What are the possible causes of failure in `ICorRuntimeHost::CurrentDomain` and `ICorRuntimeHost::CreateDomainEx`?**

Comment: Can you confirm the Excel-DNA version you're testing with, and that the problem also happens with the latest v1.7.0-rc6? I don't know of any changes in recent years that might affect this, though.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have no .config file, and then post the contents of any excel.exe.config file the computer might have (next to the excel.exe)?

Comment: Yes, the problem occurs with ExcelDna v1.7.0-rc6 (question updated).

Comment: Maybe target .NET 4.6.2, maybe check that a .NET standalone app work. Check for anti-virus or other security software.

Comment: Test with `<DnaLibrary Unsafe_CancelAddInIsolation_Unsafe="true" .... >` which skips one extra AppDomain, and thus from the second to the first of the two calls you list.

Comment: `Unsafe_CancelAddInIsolation_Unsafe="true"` seems to have done the trick. I'm guessing from the double "unsafe" that it's not desirable though. What are the implications of using it? (Thank you very much for your help, by the way)

Comment: It loads the add-in into the default AppDomain, instead of an add-in specific AppDomain. This means there would be no isolation between add-ins, and your add-in could interfere with other add-ins because the other one might find some assemblies from your add-in's AppDomain and not the isolated one. If this is the only .NET add-in running on that computer, it's not so bad.

Comment: (The Excel-DNA Google group at https://groups.google.com/g/exceldna is the best place to ask for Excel-DNA support.)